# What will be the Regular Expression to parse give output

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract the code count for the below command output. In the below example expected output is 286. What will be the regular expression to extract the code count?

[image]

Want to parse the below string in windows:

```
   1 text file.
   1 unique file.
   0 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.64  T=0.01 s (86.1 files/s, 1119.4 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C++                              1              0              0             13
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: looks like it's a output of a c program, you can change the output to only print the value you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can parse it in Linux using below:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: It is the same with my answer but you accepted your own answer over mine which was previously suggested...

Comment: @ghchoi I am getting whole line not the last integer with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can `grep` the last digits of a line by

```
grep -P "\d+$"
```

Comment: How can I parse it in windows?